# Oracle case running all prompts

Tags: oracle, plsql, case, procedure, prompt

I've made this program and I was wondering why oracle prompts for input even when it does not run the 'D' case (when 'A' is imputed for example).

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
ACCEPT p_user_letter PROMPT 'Enter an option';
DECLARE 
    v_user_letter VARCHAR2(200) := UPPER('&p_user_letter'); 
BEGIN 
   CASE v_user_letter
      when 'A' then dbms_output.put_line('A pressed');
      when 'D' then new_customer('&userEntered');
      else dbms_output.put_line('Other');
   END CASE;
END; 
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE new_customer
  (ccName IN Varchar2)
IS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Ran procedure');
END new_customer;
```

From the error message it seems like it runs a new and old version of declare which forces all uninitialized prompts to have a value, but i'm not certain and could not find out why online.

[Both new and old running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gRol.png)

Answer (score 2):

`('&userEntered');` is a [substitution variable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB).
The substitution variables are not a part of SQL, this is a feature of SQL-Plus client, it is also supported by SQL-Developer.
When you hit `Enter` (or `Run` icon in SQL-Developer), SQL-Plus first analyses your script.
 When it finds `&xxx` string in your script, then prompts the user for a value. 
When the user enters the value then SQL-Plus **substitutes** (replaces) `&xxx` with the value entered by the user.
When SQL-Plus substitutes all substitution variables, then it starts to execute this script - that is, it sends SQL commands from the script to the Oracle Database for execution.

You can think of the variable substitution in SQL-Plus as a kind of macro preprocesing.